# How to save png image file without any background color?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void SaveColorsAsBitmap(List<ColorItem> colors, string filePath)
{
    int widthColorBlock = 39; // color rectangle width
    int heightColorBlock = 18; // color rectangle height

    int imageHeight = 377; //result image height
    int imageWidth = 106;  //result image width

    var startDrawColorsPoint = new Point(45, 38); // start point (x,y) for drawing colors

    var hexBackground = "#CECECE";
    var backgroundColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hexBackground); // result image background color and hex color value

    var borderThickness = 1;  // thickness of lines around color (pixel)

    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            g.Clear(backgroundColor);

            for (int i = 0; i < colors.Count; i++)
            {
                using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(colors[i].color))
                {
                    //draw color block
                    var colorBlockPositionX = startDrawColorsPoint.X + borderThickness;
                    var colorBlockPositionY = startDrawColorsPoint.Y + (heightColorBlock * i) + borderThickness;
                    var colorBlockWidth = widthColorBlock - (borderThickness * 2);
                    var colorBlockHeight = heightColorBlock - borderThickness;

                    g.FillRectangle(brush, colorBlockPositionX, colorBlockPositionY, colorBlockWidth, colorBlockHeight);
                }
            }
        }

        // Save the bitmap as a PNG file (PNG supports transparency)
        bitmap.Save(filePath, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

the result is png file with gray background.
i can't upload the image to here because it will looks like it's transparent background but it's gray.

this line make the background gray:

```
g.Clear(backgroundColor);
```

I tried :

```
g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
```

but then it looks like with white background when viewing it in Paint:

[image: in paint]

but then the background color is white.

maybe I need to remove or change somehow the png image alpha color channel?
it seems complicated.

Comment: What are you using to view the saved image? Are you sure it supports transparent backgrounds?

Comment: i'm using paint to view the png image.  whe i upload the image to here https://imgur.com/a/je0efhd i see it without any background color but in paint i see instead the gray color white color.

Comment: @LarryBud this is how i see it in paint https://imgur.com/a/rk8LKt0

Comment: Depends on what version paint you have: https://www.pcworld.com/article/2073625/whoa-microsoft-paint-now-supports-transparency-and-layers.html#:~:text=You%20can%20now%20also%20open,create%20a%20new%20composite%20image.

Comment: Paint does not support transparency AFAIK, but Paint3D does. You can also try viewing it in a browser.

Comment: why are you calling `g.Clear` with a color?

Comment: paint.net is free and handles transparency properly.

Comment: I have windows 10, paint version 19045.3693 and it does not have transparency. I'm assuming you're talking about Windows Paint and not some 3rd party paint program (like paint.net).

Comment: Paint has gotten better and better in the last decades. Ironically it still is crap.

Comment: It's not always good news, but Windows 11 Paint 11.2309.30.0 does support transparency.